# submiting form with joda time in playframework

Tags: hibernate, session, playframework, jodatime

I use play-framework 1.2.5.

I have a html-form (groovy template) that should edit some Product.
One of the fields that I have in this Product is: "updateDate" - joda-time date type.

When I submit the form I expect to get an output with current update-date field (=current time of submitting), but instead I have the old value - previous date. What I do wrong?

Here is the form.html template fragment:

```
#{form @Products.save()}

  <input type="hidden" name="product.id" value="${product?.id}">

  %{
     org.joda.time.DateTime nowTime = org.joda.time.DateTime.now();
  }%

  <input type="hidden" name="product.updateDate" value="${nowTime}">    
   ...    

  <input type="submit" value="Save this product" id="saveProduct">
#{/form}
```

**Notice:**

The value of: "${nowTime}" is correct (I've checked) in the template, the wrong values is passed to the controller's save() method.

Comment: My decision is: public static void save(@Valid Product product) { product.updateDate = DateTime.now(); } then no need to pass date from the form to the controller. simple

Answer (score 1):

Play 1.2.x supports binding to the Date object automatically and it supports a lot of different date formats. Check, http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#binding

I don't know about DateTime support but you can always accept it as a Date instance and create a DateTime out of that if you need, alternatively you can implement the TypeBinder interface to create your own custom mappings. See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#custombinding

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible code. You make it possible for a user to fake the update date, simply by passing whatever value they like.

But I see from your comment you figured out a way to do it nicely in the controller code. I often do this in the model code by extending the save method so it sets the update time then calls super.save ()

Comment: yeah. I just was concentrated to figure out how to pass the value, but not that why I'm doing this. And, as you can see the issue was not related to passing the value but to Hibernate session where I'm comparing one existingInDBproduct.updateDate with editingProduct.updateDate

Comment: what i do when i want to update an existing record is pass in the ID separate to the POJO.  so, instead of a field product.id in the form, i use 'id', but you can still use product.X for the other values.  if you pass in product.id Play will auto load the old record and replace the values before you get a chance to compare/alter them.